# Backbone.js multiple views, one collection, one fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to generate multiple views using one collection and one fetch every 5 seconds.

Below is a working example, but both views are refreshed when fetched.
I could splice the response into multiple urls, but i want to minimize the aumount of requests.

My current problem is that i dont want all views to re-render every 5 seconds when the collection is re-fetched, only the associated view that changed.
I have tried creating multiple models inside the collection and adding the correct object in the parse function without any luck.

Response:

```
{
  "json-1": {
    "sub_1": "3",
    "sub_2": [],
  },
  "json-2": {
    "sub_1": [],
    "sub_2": "1",
  },
}
```

// Client

```
const APICollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: (models, options) => {
        this.id = options.id;
    },
    url: () => {
        return 'https://url.url/' + this.id;
    },
    model: APIModel,
        parse: (resp) => {
        return resp;
    },
});

const ViewOne = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.bind('sync', this.render, this);
        this.update();
        _.bindAll(this, 'update');
    },
    render: function (n, collection) {
        // Render view
    },
    update: function () {
        let self = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            update: true, remove: false, success: function () {
                setTimeout(self.update, 5000);
            }
        });
    }
});

// Also updates when re-fetched
const ViewTwo = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.bind('sync', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function (n, collection) {
        // Render function
    }
});

let col = APICollection([], {id: 'someid'});
new ViewOne({collection: col, el: $("#one")});
new ViewTwo({collection: col, el: $("#two")});
```

**Update

To clarify: "only the associated view that changed". By this i mean that 'ViewOne' should only be re-rendered when 'json-1' has changed, and 'ViewTwo' shouldn't re-render. currently the full response is sent to both views.

Comment: "...only the associated view that changed." - you'll have to clarify this, do certain models in the collection relate to certain views? what makes one view different from another in the way it works with the collection?

Comment: i will update the question

Comment: If your response doesn't return an array, you should be using `Backbone.Model` not `Backbone.Collection`, then you can listen to `change:attr` events in each view.

Comment: That, works thanks :). can you add this as answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with an API which returns an Object, not an array of Objects, the best approach is to use a `Backbone.Model` directly.

```
update: function () {
    let self = this;
    this.model.fetch({
        update: true, remove: false, success: function () {
            setTimeout(self.update, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

The model is still fetched the same way as the collection, but the Views can listen to specific attributes on the model, instead of:

```
this.collection.bind('sync', this.render, this);
```

The following can be used:

```
this.model.bind('change:json-1', this.render, this);
```

**Tip:** Better to `listenTo` rather than bind, it is safer (see [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo))

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:json-1', this.render);
```

Comment: `setTimeout(self.update, 5000);` won't work since the context will be lost the first time the timeout callback is executed. Instead, you should use the `context` option of the `fetch` function and pass `this.update.bind(this)` to `setTimeout`.

Comment: Also, with this technique, at the first error, the 5 sec loop will stop.

Comment: @EmileBergeron - not sure the context will be lost, but certainly some better error handling would be good. One point I'd add, if it were my code, I'd add the re-fetch mechanism inside the model, not the view, in terms of model/view abstraction, it's a little cleaner.

Comment: It will be lost because you're passing a function reference to `setTimeout` and it'll be called as-is (like `callback()`) without any context.

Comment: Nope, I wouldn't add the re-fetch to the model because it is specific to the app. What if you want to reuse the model without the re-fetch?